# Facing issue to make --prod --aot build of angular4 project when number of components are large,.How to resolve this?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have working on angular4 project, Its a admin theme, Everything works fine. I also create build with

> ng build

successfully. But when I try to make build using

> ng build --prod --aot

. It takes long time to compile and build. If I decrease the number of components, then it works fine. I don't understand what is the issue?